# Way to easily see which assets are not used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I've inherited a rails app that had been used a few times over for various, different applications.  In doing so, it looks as with each iteration, the developers simply copied in the new assets (images, javascript, etc) without starting fresh, so now I've got folders full of assets I'm sure aren't used.

I want to clean this up, as I'm responsible for the current iteration.

Is there a quick/easy way (a script perhaps) to filter out what is used and what isn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining which assets are not being used in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469767/determining-which-assets-are-not-being-used-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

if you have very verbose logs try this script (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488684/1440599)

```
grep -Eo ‘GET /(.*(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.css|.js))[ \?]’ [the-log].log > ~/assets.txt
```

of course, this doesn't take into account the time the assets are used (some may be obsolete) depending on how long the application has been logged so you'll have to take this into account